# Kivy BoxLayout.orientation

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to kivy.
There is something about the `orientation` property of the BoxLayout class which is confusing me: if i set the orientation to vertical the child widgets are actually set up horizontally and vice versa. What am i understanding wrong? Why is that decided to be so and not other way around which is more intuitive?
Here are my codes:

```
# main.py
from kivy.app import App

class LernApp(App):

    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LernApp().run()


# lern.kv
BoxLayout
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button
        text: "Button1"
    Button
        text: "Button2"
```

This produces this window:

[image]

Comment: I do not understand "child widgets are actually set up horizontally", they are on top of each other, which in my opinion is vertical arrangement.

Answer (score 4):

The widgets are stacked *vertically*.
So the **meaning of orientation is how to stack widgets** inside the BoxLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you want exactly, but I think you want the buttons horizontally

try this :

from kivy.app import App

class LernApp(App):

```
# lern.kv


return BoxLayout("""


        orientation: "horizontal"


        Button:

            text: "Button1"

        Button:

            text: "Button2"

"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LernApp().run()
```

Or try this

from kivy.app import App

class LernApp(App):

```
 # lern.kv
 return BoxLayout("""
        orientation: "horizontal"

        Button:

            text: "Button1"

        Button:

            text: "Button2"

"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LernApp().run()
```